# Getting Duration of Video/Audio in react Native for Progress Bar Impmentation

Tags: react-native, process, expo, audio-streaming, react-native-sound

I am currently implementing a react Native streaming app using expo version and I am having some difficulties. please feel free to answer any of the questions or just one and in any other of your choice.

> 1) Implementing a Progress bar as the sound plays. To do this, I need
>   to get the duration of the song, then I use Math.Floor to do
>   calculations for the progress bar but i am currently unable to get the
>   duration of the currently playing track. Any ideas on how to do this
>   using either the Sound Object or Video compoment will be greatful.
>
> 2) I need to be able to play background sound from my app and from
>   some research, it seems to be impossible with Expo version. Any hacks
>   around this ???
>
> 3) How do I determine wether the current playing track using the Audio
>   component has finished  ??
>
> 4) I want a situation where I can stop any other sound in the device
>   when sound is played from my device. Any idea on how to do this ??
>
> 5) Any Recommendations for me on streaming apps using react Native

Answer (score 2):

I can help you with first three questions.

1, To get the total duration of the audio use `playbackStatus.durationMillis` and 
   to get the current duration of the audio use `playbackStatus.positionMillis`

Get the playbackStatus by using

```
export const createAudio = async () => {
    const source = require('../../../assets/audio/storiesAudio/storyAudio.mp3');
    const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(source,
        {
         shouldPlay: false,
         isLooping: false,
        },
    onPlaybackStatusUpdate,
    );
    this.setState({playbackInstance: sound});
}

onPlaybackStatusUpdate = async (playbackStatus) => {
    await this.setState({ playbackStatus });
    if (this.state.playbackStatus.isPlaying) {
    }
  }
```

To convert millis to minutes and seconds

```
   export const millisToMinutesAndSeconds = (millis) => {
       let minutes = Math.floor(millis / 60000);
       let seconds = ((millis % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(0);
       return (seconds == 60 ? (minutes+1) + ":00" : minutes + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : 
       "") + seconds);
   }
```

2, To make the audio play in the background

```
const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
    sourceAudioFile,
    {
        shouldPlay: true, //To play the audio when the component is loadded
        isLooping: false,
    },
    onPlaybackStatusUpdate,
);
```

3, To check whether the current audio track is finished playing, use `playbackStatus.didJustFinish`

Comment: Add if (!millis) return '0:00' at the first line of millisToMinutesAndSeconds to cater edge cases e.g undefined, null, NaN